# Let $a_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} + \sin\frac{n \pi}{2}$ find $\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty}{a_n}$ and $\liminf_\limits{n\to \infty} {a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> a) Let $a_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} + \sin\frac{n \pi}{2}$ find $\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty} {a_n}$ and $\liminf_\limits{n\to \infty} {a_n}$
>
> b) Let $a_n = (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n(-1)^n} \cdot \frac{n}{2n+1} + \cos\frac{n \pi}{2}$ find a sub-sequence such that $\lim_\limits{k\to \infty}a_{n_k}= \frac{e}{2}+1$

---

I am not sure if what I am doing is correct but for the first part I checked what would happen if $n$ is odd and $n$ is even

if $n$ is even then $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ would be $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sin\frac{n \pi}{2}$ would be $\sin\frac{2n \pi}{2}$

if $n$ is odd then $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ would be $\frac{-1}{n^2}$ and $\sin\frac{n \pi}{2}$ is $\sin(\pi n-\frac{\pi}{2})=-\cos(\pi n)$

taking the limit as $n$ approaches infinity would be $0$ for all cases for $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$

and for $\sin\frac{n \pi}{2}$ the value would be $1,-1$ or $0$ so I assume that $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\sup {a_n}=1$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\inf {a_n}=-1$ but on the other hand the limit of $\sin\frac{n \pi}{2}$ does not exist

For the second part:

In a similar way $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n(-1)^n}=e$ if $n$ is even and if $n$ is odd $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n(-1)^n}=\frac{1}{e}$

for $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(\frac{n}{2n+1})$ it is $0$ regardless of $n$ beind odd or even

lastly for $\cos \frac{n \pi}{2}$ similar to the question before if $n$ is even we get $\cos{n \pi}=1,-1$ and if $n$ is odd then $\cos (\frac{2n\it}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2})=0$

I thought about the sub-sequence where $a_{n_k}$ is $a_{4k}$ but as before the limit with $\cos$ does not exist

how to approach these questions? Thanks for any tips and help

Comment: Note that $\sup_{n\ge 1} \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}+\sin(n\pi/2)\right)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning and conclusion for part a are correct. More generally:

- if $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n)=0$ then the [$\limsup$ and $\liminf$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior) of $(a_n)$ are the same as those of $(b_n)$;
- the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of a sequence are its highest and lowest [subsequential limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequential_limit), and the subsequential limits of a [periodic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence) are its values;
- a sequence has a limit (if and) only if its
  $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ coincide.

For part b, beware that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac n{2n+1}$ is $\frac12$, not $0$. That said, you are right to think 'about the sub-sequence where $a_{n_k}$ is $a_{4k}$', and there is no problem with 'the limit with $\cos$' for this subsequence, since $\cos\frac{(4k)\pi}2=1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a MUCH simpler way to do this. In particular, you may want to recheck the definitions of $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$. In particular, the limit of a sequence may not exist [as you are observing here] even though both the $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$ of the sequence exists [as you also seem to be observing here].

(a) As already noted, $|\frac{1}{n^2}|$ goes to $0$. Thus the following is true:
$$\lim \sup_n a_n = \lim \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sin \frac{\pi n}{2} \ = \ 1.$$
[Indeed $\sin \frac{ \pi n}{2}$ is $1$ for all $ n \equiv_4 1$.] Likewise:
$$\lim \inf_n a_n = \lim \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sin \frac{\pi n}{2} \ = \ -1.$$ [Indeed $\sin \frac{ \pi n}{2}$ is $-1$ for all $n \equiv_4 3$.]

(b) HINT: Why not just take $n$ so that both $(-1)^n=1$  and $\cos \frac{\pi n}{2} = 1$? It is straightforward to see that $n$ a multiple of $4$ satisfies.